# JQuery dialog: how to get the dialog to update with server side errors/messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-dialog

I am attempting to use a JQuery dialog to popup a window upon let's say, an add button, which will therefore show a dialog with a Html.BeginForm() form within.

Either by using the buttons from the dialog, or putting a dialog within, I wish to submit the form, and then get the form back, either to show an update that the add is successful, or to show that there are some issues with the form (eg: server side errors)

EG:

```
public ActionResult EventSave(EventManageModel model)
{
        if (fake error, db save failed)
            ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "DB save failed!");
        return PartialView("EventManage", model);
}
```

I think I got the client side validation right, by using :

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#EventManage");
```

But my big question is actually server side validation/server side data retrieval. I don't think Remote Validation works for me because this kind of errors would be more/less form-based errors instead of a specific textbox for example.

How can I get this to work? I have really no clue, I have tried theoretically everywhere to get this to work.

At the moment, when the dialog form submits, I have something like this:

```
      "Save": function () {
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#EventManage");

                    if ($("#EventManage").valid()) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/Home/EventSave",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: $("#EventManage").serialize(),
                            success: function (result) {
                                $("#EventManage").html(result);
                            },
                            error: function (result) {
                                $("#EventManage").html(result);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
```

I am not getting what I want however, the dialog doesn't seem to be updating to and updated partial view, with no errors.

I am following this example actually, on how to get it to work:

http://iwantmymvc.com/dialog-form-with-jqueryui-and-mvc-3

Please give some tips on how to get this thing done? :)

**EDIT:**

My EventManage partial form:-

```
@model Harrods.Web.Models.EventManageModel


<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("EventSave", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EventManage", @class = "Dialog" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please correct the errors below and try again:", new { @class = "ui-state-error ui-corner-all" })<br />
        <br />
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Event Details</legend>
        <br />
        @Html.Hidden("Id")
        <div class="editor-label-dialog">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Event_Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field-dialog">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Event_Name)
            <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Event_Name)
        </div>
        <p class="clear"></p>
        <br />
        <div class="editor-label-dialog">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Event_Date)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field-dialog">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Event_Date)
            <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Event_Date)
        </div>
        <p class="clear"></p>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="addNew" value="Save" />
        <div class='loading' style='display: none'><img src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/img/loading.gif")" title="Loading" /></div>
        </fieldset>
}
</div>
```

**EDIT2**

It seems like I got it to work for >> success: function (result)

but it doesn't go into the error: function (result)

even though there's already an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show error messages that are not specific to some given input and that were added to the modelstate you could use the `ValidationSummary` helper. So put the following somewhere inside the partial:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Comment: @RicL, is it inside the `EventManage` partial? Also did you make sure that an error was actually added to the modelstate from the server? Then did you make sure that the success AJAX callback was called on the client and that the correct portion of the DOM was updated?

Comment: 1) It is in. 2) Yup, I added the ModelState.AddModelError directly. 3) and 4) not really understood (forgive my newbishness)

Comment: @RicL, now that you have posted your code I see that you used `Html.ValidationSummary(false, ...`. Does using `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` make any difference?

Comment: setting it to true will not show the error message. Strange enough. Anyway, I seem to make it work whereby it goes into success, but not error. Any reason why it goes into success even though there's a ModelState Error?

Comment: @RicL, the error callback is called only if the controller action fails. For example if it throws an exception. You are not throwing any exception. You are simply returning a partial view with HTTP status code 200. So the success callback is called.

Comment: I see.. sorry for the mix up. Thanks a lot for your clarification mate. What about the ValidationSummary(true/false)? what's the difference?

Comment: @RicL, the parameter indicates whether you want to exclude property errors. If you set it to true the validation summary helper will show only errors that were added to the modelstate and that do not have a corresponding input field (sort of like global validation error). If you set it to false it will show all errors. So you could have property validation errors shown twice: once in the validation summary and once next to each corresponding input field.

Comment: Thanks a million mate. Spent nearly 16 hours only to find out that I've already solve this. Real queer!

Answer (score 3):

The .ajax error: is NOT called if the modelstate has errors, its called if the ajax request fails.

What you have to do is to check the result and se if there is errors. This can be done in multiple ways like Json.

Return a Json object if EventSave succeeds, and return a partialView if it fails. Then you can check if it succeeds and handle the cases.

Here is an example

The JS code:

```
"Save": function () {
                $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#CreateGroup")
                if ($("#CreateGroup").valid()) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Participant/CreateGroup",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: $("#CreateGroup").serialize(),
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.result == "success") {
                                $("#GroupAddDialog").dialog("close");
                                LoadList();
                            }
                            else {
                                $("#GroupAddDialog").html(result);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

And controller code:

```
if(Success)
{
     return Json(new
            {
               result = "success"
            });
}
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save in db");
return PartialView("_CreateGroup", model);
```

Comment: Opened my eyes to the source of the problem. Thanks.
One question though. In my code $("#GroupAddDialog").html(result); did not work.  But this worked:$("#GroupAddDialog").html(result.responseText);
The question is why this one works for others: $("#GroupAddDialog").html(result);

Is it because I am using Ajax.BeginForm ?

Comment: Well it depends on what you controller returns? Result is what you get back from the controller so please share the controller code.

Comment: public ActionResult Create(FinAccountVM accountVM)
        {
                // I removed saving and success code from here 
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Failed");
                Response.StatusCode = 400;
                return PartialView(accountVM);
        }

Comment: I need all code to tell you why one is working and the other is not. But just use the one that works.

Comment: Curiosity killed the cat.. I will just use the one that works ;)
Thanks TobiasW

Comment: In most case I agree with you, but since my code is almost 4 years old I'm a bit off here :)